# Mathematical Guarantee in Trignometric Functions of CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

CUDA supports [mathematical functions](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE). But do they provide **any** guarantee like if I compute `sin(x)` the result would the closet representable value to the mathematical value of `sin(x)`? If the answer is no, is there any alternative if we want to stay in GPU? Something like it always return an upper bound or always a lower bound (but possibly not the closest possible one).

Comment: Quoting directly from what you linked to "For accuracy information for this function see the CUDA C++ Programming Guide, Appendix E.1, Table 7." -- i.e. [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#standard-functions)

Comment: `sin(x)` is irrational for any `x` that is non-zero rational. An irrational number has infinite decimals. Any means you want to use to represent this number will require infinite resources. In particular, you need infinite memory in a computer to store a single irrational number. So the answer is no: There is no human way of representing mathematically perfectly an irrational number.

Comment: If you wish to have IEEE 754 compliance you may consider disabling "fast math" option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CUDA Appendix](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#standard-functions) Suggests that the value provided by the API are not accurate. There is a difference of, 1/2 [ulps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) in their value. <strike>(when compared between host and device)</strike>.

However, for all practical purposes, these values are accurate.

Anyway if you want to perform symbolic operations with high-level precision, using float precision makes it inaccurate.

Comment: The ULPS tolerances don't mean what you imply in your answer

Comment: My understanding is as follows. The host and device method calls will return the values close to the actual value. There is a difference of 1or2 uips between the host and device. So, I assumed that this can be considered to be the difference between the actual value and the value of host and device.

Noe, given that 1/2 ulps for a float is very small and comparable to the loss of precision due to float, this difference can be neglected.

Please do let me know, if i am missing something and wrong in something.

Comment: The last place errors are not between a host and a GPU calculation. They are between the true result represented as a correctly rounded IEEE 754 floating point type, and the library result provided on the GPU. The host has absolutely no role in the last place error bounds provided

Comment: The last place errors are actually between the mathematically correct result to infinite precision, and the numerical result returned be the GPU. Taking into account that the correct mathematical result can be anywhere between two adjacent representable floating point numbers, 1/2 ULP is obviously the best that can be attained, regardless whether on a GPU or CPU. But due to the extreme effort required to produce a "correctly rounded" result with 1/2 ULP error, "faithfully rounded" results (1 ULP) or a few ULPs are usually considered a good compromise.

Comment: @tera Lets have an example to see if I understood you correctly. According to the CUDA Appendix, `tanh(x)` for double-precision floating-point has "2 (full range)" as its maximum ULP error. Does this mean the mathematical value is always within 2 (and not 3) representable values below or above the return value? Also, what is "full-range"? Finally, is there a way to control, or at least know, whether the mathematical value is smaller or larger?

Comment: @Koosha [CUDA Programming Guide, section E.1](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#standard-functions): "The maximum error is stated as the absolute value of the difference in ulps between a correctly rounded [single-precision | double-precision] result and the result returned by the CUDA library function". "Full range" means across the entire range of floating-point operands.

Comment: I found this at [CUDA Doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#standard-functions) which is unfortunate. "The error bounds are generated from extensive but not exhaustive tests, so they are not guaranteed bounds." Therefore, there is NO guarantee!!

Comment: @njuffa Thanks for setting this straight - while usually the error is given in the way I described, the appendix of the Programming Guide uses a different convention.